# Changing from integers to strings in login system

Tags: java, loops

I currently have a login system that requires only numbers to login. Meaning the Username, Password and Student number (all required to login) are numbers only. I am looking for a way to change the Username and password to words instead of numbers. How would I do this? I tried using strings but was unable to take an input from the console. Here is my code;

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int UserID = 5555; 
    final int Password = 1234;
    final int StudentNumber = 22334455;


    int EnteredUserID; 
    int EnteredPassword;
    int EnteredStudentNumber;
    for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) { 
        if (s < 3) { 
            System.out.println("Enter your UserID to access lift;"); 
            EnteredUserID = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Your UserID is >>> " + EnteredUserID);
            System.out.println("Enter your password to authenticate login;");
            EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Password Entered is >>> " + EnteredPassword);
            System.out.println("Enter your student number to finalise login and authentication;");
            EnteredStudentNumber = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Student Number Entered is >>> " + EnteredStudentNumber);
            if (UserID == EnteredUserID && (Password == EnteredPassword) 
                    && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Athentication complete!");
                System.out.println("***Elevator access granted!***");
                System.out.println("Welcome..."); 
                Elevator a = new Elevator(); 
                Elevator.selectFloor();
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong UserID, Password or Student Number. Please try again."); 
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Access Denied!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the username and password to strings and using `console.nextLine()` and `console.next()`, but neither seemed to work and store the what was entered.

Comment: Did you also remember to change `==` to `equals` when comparing the `Strings`?

Comment: Don't compare `String`s with `==`. You need to use `equals()`.

Comment: Have you changed nextInt() to next or nextLine()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `int` with `String`

Replace `console.nextInt();` with `console.next();` or `console.nextLine();`

and finally, use `.equals()` when comparing strings:

```
UserID == EnteredUserID
```

Should be:

```
UserID.equals(EnteredUserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a fast way to convert a number to a string then just do the following:

```
   int number = 10;
   String toText = ""+number;
```

Is that your question or?